# Can we skip an object during avro serialization like the feature "Transient" in "JAVA Serialization"?

Tags: java, serialization, avro

Is there a feature in Avro during serialization which can skip some elements in the Avro schema?

Comment: I don't understand the reason. If you don't want to have some field in your AVRO object why don't you remove it from the schema? It's possible to avoid filling in the field with a data if the field has `default` tag

Comment: Just want to know if there is a feature available in AVRO. I didn't understand the default mechanism. Can you please explain @kbo

Comment: If you add tag `default` to your AVRO schema then this field is not required to fill in manually and default value will be set. You can find more information here https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html

Comment: But if default it will be serialized anyways, it wont skip the serialization. @kbo